# Redirect 301 multidominio: diferente redireccionamiento según el host

Tags: .htaccess, redirección, mod-rewrite

Tengo una web multidominio: único servidor, único .htaccess, 2 dominios (.com, .es).

La mayoría de las URLs las he podido redireccionar al no coincidir las urls en español e inglés:

```
redirect 301 /las-noticias.php http://www.dominio.es/noticias
redirect 301 /the-news.php htpp://www.dominio.com/news
```

Pero tengo problemas para cuando la parte relativa coincide, por ejemplo si las URLs fuesen:

```
http://www.dominio.es/video-01.php
http://www.dominio.com/video-01.php
```

Al querer redireccionarlas quedaría:

```
redirect 301 /video-01.php http://www.dominio.es/xxxx
redirect 301 /video-01.php htpp://www.dominio.com/yyyy
```

Como se puede ver, hay conflicto al coincidir las 2 direcciones relativas. Con `redirect` no se puede usar URLs absolutas, ¿hay alguna alternativa? Pensé en hacerlo con `rewriterule` pero no tengo claro como plantearlo.

Comment: Una pequeña corrección a tu pregunta: no es "*la parte relativa*", `/video-01.php` sigue siendo una URL absoluta (y `Redirect` sólo acepta URLs absolutas). Lo que no incluye es el host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Redireccionar según el dominio con [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost)**

La forma más sencilla es usando la directiva [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

```py
<VirtualHost www.dominio.es>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dominio.es
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/www.dominio.es
    ServerName www.dominio.es
    #Otras configuraciones

    Redirect 301 /las-noticias.php /noticias

</VirtualHost>
```

- También se podría utilizar una directiva [`<If>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)

**Redireccionar según el dominio con [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)**

Pero también se puede hacer con [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), que te permite reglas más complejas para otros casos que lo requieran.

```py
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^video-01\.php$ xxxx [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^video-01\.php$ yyyy [R=301,NC]
```

- Cada [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) funciona como condición para el siguiente [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).
- `^` coincide con el inicio de la URL, `$` coincide con la posición final.
- Los puntos son caracteres especiales en regex, por eso hay que escaparlos con una `\`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ahora que lo veo la opción de virtualhost me parece evidente, pero no se me pasó por la cabeza en ningún momento.